# How to list all interpolation algorithms installed in Julia's DifferentialEquations?

Tags: julia, differential-equations

How do I list all of the installed interpolation algorithms from the DifferentialEquations.jl?

My solver always uses "Interpolation: 3rd order Hermite".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The interpolation method associated with the given solver is mentioned here: http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/solvers/ode_solve. Many methods, like `CVODE_BDF`, utilize a Hermite interpolation. But there's a good number of standard methods, like `Tsit5` and `Vern9` which utilize special interpolations.

Comment: This link seems to be a 404 now. Is there an updated link?